# auto_now_add=True with null=True

Tags: django, datetime

I have modified on my model by adding a DateTime field as the following

```
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
```

when I migrated on the previous rows, this column is set to now value not null as the following from the admin page.

Date joined: Oct. 9, 2019, 1:32 a.m.

any explanation please ?

Comment: please, guys, need an explanation for my question, don't hesitate for any explanation.

Comment: Do you mean you were hoping for all of the previous rows to retain `date_joined` as null instead of the migration time? I'm not 100% sure if this will work but you might try starting with `date_joined = models.DateTimeField(null=True)`, creating a migration, then changing it to `date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)` and creating a second migration. Not sure if that will work though.

Comment: if I don't put null=True and write it date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  the default will be the migration time? and if yes why when I run the server , asked me to put a default value for the previous rows?